# php GLOBALS session file

Tags: php, mysql, compiler-errors, config

I am developing a membership system and I have hit a stopper, normally I would only post questions on here but i have a error I can not work out and have been on this error for over a hour.

the error I am getting is:

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/ob219/public_html/membership/core/init.php on line 10*

I just cant see the bug in the code, would appriciate a second pair of eyes to look over the code.

**Code**

```
    <?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(),
        'host' => '#####',
        'username' => '###',
        'password' => 's####',
        'db' => '####'
    ),
    'remeber' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . 'php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'mysql' => array(),` should be `'mysql' => array(`

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
   'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '#####',
        'username' => '###',
        'password' => 's####',
        'db' => '####'
    ),
    'remeber' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(), <===== syntax error here. you don't want the close) and comma
```